How to rate limit a deferred HTTP client in Twisted?
I have an HTTP client written in Twisted that sends requests to an API of some site from a deferred. It goes something like this (somewhat simplified):
from json import loads

from core import output

from twisted.python.log import msg
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent, HTTPConnectionPool, _HTTP11ClientFactory, readBody
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory


class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):

    def getContext(self, hostname, port):
        return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)


class QuietHTTP11ClientFactory(_HTTP11ClientFactory):
    # To shut up the garbage in the log
    noisy = False


class Output(output.Output):
    def start(self):
        myQuietPool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor)
        myQuietPool._factory = QuietHTTP11ClientFactory
        self.agent = Agent(
            reactor,
            contextFactory=WebClientContextFactory(),
            pool=myQuietPool
        )

    def stop(self):
        pass

    def write(self, event):
        messg = 'Whatever'
        self.send_message(messg)

    def send_message(self, message):
        headers = Headers({
            b'User-Agent': [b'MyApp']
        })
        url = 'https://api.somesite.com/{}'.format(message)
        d = self.agent.request(b'GET', url.encode('utf-8'), headers, None)

        def cbBody(body):
            return processResult(body)

        def cbPartial(failure):
            failure.printTraceback()
            return processResult(failure.value)

        def cbResponse(response):
            if response.code in [200, 201]:
                return
            else:
                msg('Site response: {} {}'.format(response.code, response.phrase))
                d = readBody(response)
                d.addCallback(cbBody)
                d.addErrback(cbPartial)
                return d

        def cbError(failure):
            failure.printTraceback()

        def processResult(result):
            j = loads(result)
            msg('Site response: {}'.format(j))

        d.addCallback(cbResponse)
        d.addErrback(cbError)
        return d

This works fine but the site is rate limiting the requests and starts dropping them if they are arriving too fast. So, I need to rate-limit the client too and make sure that it isn't sending the requests too fast - yet they aren't lost, so some kind of buffering/queuing is needed. I don't need a precise rate limiting, like "no more than X requests per second"; just some reasonable delay (lik 1 second) after each request is fine.
Unfortunately, I can't use sleep() from a deferred, so some other approach is necessesary.
From googoing around, it seems that the basic idea is to do something like
self.transport.pauseProducing()
delay = 1 # seconds
self.reactor.callLater(delay, self.transport.resumeProducing)

at least according to this answer. But the code there doesn't work "as is" - SlowDownloader is expected to take a parameter (a reactor), so SlowDownloader() causes an error.
I also found this answer, which uses the interesting idea of using the factory as a storage, so you don't need to implement your own queues and stuff - but it deals with rate-limiting on the server side, while I need to rate-limit the client.
I feel that I'm pretty close to the solution but I still can't figure out how exactly to combine the information from these two answers, in order to produce working code, so any help would be appreciated.

Delaying everything by 1 second isn't a rate limit.  If you had X requests/second before and you insert a 1 second delay for everything, you have X requests/second after, just offset forward by 1 second.  Maybe all you need is an error handling that does a retry?  You probably want that anyway since "the server thinks I am sending requests too fast" is only one possible way that your requests can fail to have the desired effect.

I'm afraid I don't understand. If I retry after the server tells me that I'm sending requests too fast, I'll be sending even more requests to the server than I'm doing now - unless I delay the retry, which I don't know how to do. And if I can simply insert a delay after each request, I obviously won't be hitting the "X request per second" limit of the server.

I don't follow your reasoning.  I don't think it will help, but if you want to try inserting a delay, https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/core/howto/time.html shows how to do this.

Sorry, I don't understand what I'm supposed to do in the context of the example I gave. Should I, instead of self.send_message(messg) do task.deferLater(reactor, 1, self.send_message, messg)? Or should I, in send_message, where I'm now doing d = self.agent.request(... do something like d = task.deferLater(reactor, 1, self.agent.request, ...)? Maybe I am completely misunderstanding you. Can you propose a better answer to the problem "server complains that client is sending requests too fast, so send them more slowly"?

OK, I managed to solve the problem. The code below does what I need - it makes sure that there is at least a 2-second delay between messages, and that the messages are sent in the right order. It works - the server no longer returns 429 errors and the messages are correctly ordered. It's not a generic rate-limiting solution (i.e., one making sure that exactly X messages are sent every Y seconds) but it does what I need. It's also not very elegant - I'm manually keeping track of when was a request last sent, maintain a queue of requests, in order to make sure that they will be sent in the right order, and so on. If someone knows how to achieve all this with Twisted's built-in methods, please create a separate answer and I'll accept it.
from json import loads
from time import time

from core import output

from twisted.python.log import msg
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.web.client import Agent, HTTPConnectionPool, _HTTP11ClientFactory, readBody
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory


class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):

    def getContext(self, hostname, port):
        return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)


class QuietHTTP11ClientFactory(_HTTP11ClientFactory):
    # To shut up the garbage in the log
    noisy = False


class Output(output.Output):
    def start(self):
        myQuietPool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor)
        myQuietPool._factory = QuietHTTP11ClientFactory
        self.agent = Agent(
            reactor,
            contextFactory=WebClientContextFactory(),
            pool=myQuietPool
        )
        self.last_sent = 0
        self.requests_queue = []

    def stop(self):
        pass

    def write(self, event):
        messg = 'Whatever'
        self.send_message(messg)

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.requests_queue.append(message)
        now = time()
        if now - self.last_sent < 2.0:
            # Make sure there's at least a 2-second delay between requests
            deferLater(reactor, 2.0, self.send_message, message)
            return
        message = self.requests_queue.pop(0)
        headers = Headers({
            b'User-Agent': [b'MyApp']
        })
        url = 'https://api.somesite.com/{}'.format(message)
        d = self.agent.request(b'GET', url.encode('utf-8'), headers, None)

        def cbBody(body):
            return processResult(body)

        def cbPartial(failure):
            failure.printTraceback()
            return processResult(failure.value)

        def cbResponse(response):
            if response.code in [200, 201]:
                return
            else:
                msg('Site response: {} {}'.format(response.code, response.phrase))
                d = readBody(response)
                d.addCallback(cbBody)
                d.addErrback(cbPartial)
                return d

        def cbError(failure):
            failure.printTraceback()

        def processResult(result):
            j = loads(result)
            msg('Site response: {}'.format(j))

        d.addCallback(cbResponse)
        d.addErrback(cbError)
        return d


Nobody has suggested a better solution, so I'm going to mark this answer as accepted.

If cbError represents the conditions under which you want to perform a retry after a delay then you can rewrite that function like:
async def cbError(failure):
    failure.printTraceback()
    await deferLater(reactor, 3.0, lambda: None)
    return self.send_message(message)


Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I'm still getting error 429 (Too many requests) from the server, it drops some of the messages, and the ones it accepts seem to be out of order (i.e., not in the order in which the client has sent them). I must pause after each message is sent and before the next one is sent - not pause after an error has already occurred. The server does not want to receive more than 1 message per second.

I kinda managed to get rid of the errors, by adding another callback (before all the others) to another async function that does the same trick (await deferLater(reactor, 5.0, lambda: None)) before calling response.deliverBody() but it is still not good enough. Some (fewer) messages are still lost and some are still out of order. Just no more 429 errors from the server.
